# What is the point of usedforsecurity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, hash

The parameter `usedforsecurity` was added to every hash function in hashlib in Python 3.9.

> Changed in version 3.9: All hashlib constructors take a keyword-only argument usedforsecurity with default value True. A false value allows the use of insecure and blocked hashing algorithms in restricted environments. False indicates that the hashing algorithm is not used in a security context, e.g. as a non-cryptographic one-way compression function.

However, this provides *zero* guidance on

1. When you should use `usedforsecurity`
2. When you should *not* use `usedforsecurity`
3. What "restricted environments" are

And while I'm not a security researcher, I darn well know md5 is *not* secure in any sense of the word. Consequently, the name `usedforsecurity` boggles my mind in more ways than one.

What is the point of `usedforsecurity`?

Comment: "False indicates that the hashing algorithm is not used in a security context" is a lot more than "*zero* guidance" on when this parameter is supposed to be used.

Comment: Have a look at Python's changelog for a link to the lengthy issue/discussion that introduced it.

Comment: @user2357112 It doesn't make any sense given that a) if there isn't any tradeoff then why would you ever turn it off b) md5 (and several others) is clearly not supposed to be used in a security context ever. Imagine there being a button in your room with a label: "press to extend your lifespan". Wouldn't that be a wee bit suspicious to you?

Comment: Others have pointed you to additional materials that you should conduct more research around the rationale for the change.

Comment: The basic idea is to prevent programmers from using *insecure* hash algorithms by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR For almost everyone, ignore the flag, it has no effect whatsoever.

---

The full story involves [FIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Information_Processing_Standards) and how that gets exposed as a python API.

For our purposes, FIPS is a standard that [supposedly specifies](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=139819485423701&w=2) a safe set of practices. In certain scenarios (e.g. writing software for US government agencies), you are *forced* to comply with FIPS.

To comply with FIPS, your python would have had FIPS mode turned on by building python with FIPS enabled from source. This is the "restricted environment" mentioned in the documentation. If you have a standard python build, then you aren't complying with FIPS and the flag literally does nothing.

One aspect of FIPS is restricting the hash functions you are allowed to use. In particular, MD5 is not allowed under FIPS. When you use MD5 in a FIPS environment, you will encounter an error. That is what the introduction of `usedforsecurity` is supposed to fix: give you an escape hatch in the case that you truly want to use MD5 in a FIPS environment. The parameter is designed to be specified at each call site so it can be audited on a case by case basis.

There seems to be confusion [on many sides](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/53462#issuecomment-1093510157) that `usedforsecurity` has anything to do with security. It's not. Having it set to `False` doesn't reduce your security. On FIPS enabled environments, it does however switch your implementation of the hash function to one that was explicitly certified.

In conclusion, for all intents and purposes, the parameter might as well have been called `exceptionforfips` because that's the singular purpose it serves: as an escape hatch if you happen to work under a FIPS environment and still need to use a FIPS non-compliant hash. It is quite unfortunate it is part of the API for *all* users with a seriously misleading name.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation given in the docs is pretty clear on when you should or shouldn't use `usedforsecurity`: pass `False` if you're not using the algorithm for security purposes.

The effects do deserve more explanation. On most Python builds, this parameter does nothing. Insecure algorithms are enabled by default.

"Restricted environments" would mostly be rare builds of Python using the [OpenSSL FIPS module](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.2/man7/fips_module.html) (or OpenSSL FIPS mode on pre-3.0 OpenSSL) to disable insecure algorithms. If you pass `usedforsecurity=False`, Python will tell OpenSSL to allow insecure algorithms anyway (see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Modules/_hashopenssl.c#L869-L871), [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Modules/_hashopenssl.c#L887-L893) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Modules/_hashopenssl.c#L338-L343), if you'd like to see the code). If you're genuinely not using the algorithm for anything that needs cryptographic-strength guarantees, this is okay.

If you'd like to read more, you can also check the [issue discussion](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/53462) that originally led to introducing this flag.